# How to disable reCAPTCHA v2 with test keys for automation

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, recaptcha

This might be really obvious but I still have not found a solution. For automation purposes how do you disable a reCAPTCHA using the site key and secret key? Is it done through setting a variable in selenium or a console command?

I looked online and every source just says to "put in" the test keys, which leads me to believe it's something super simple I'm just missing.[Google reCAPTCHA FAQ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CiVRK.png)